# About 'pseq' in Haskell

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing, ghc

Consider the following two statements:

```
(a `par` b) `pseq` (a + b)
```

and

```
a `par` (b `pseq` (a + b))
```

Can someone explain how their behavior differ from each other?

For the first one, if the main thread has done with computing `b` but the spark computing `a` hasn't finished, will the main thread proceed to compute `a + b`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`par a b` is semantically equivalent to `b`, but it gives the hint that it might be useful to start evaluating `a` early.  On the otherhand `pseq` forces the evaluation of its first argument, but is simply the (lazy) identity function in its second argument.

So,

```
(a `par` b) `pseq` (a + b)
```

is semantically equivalent to

```
b `pseq` (a + b)
```

which is equivalent to

```
a `par` (b `pseq` (a + b))
```

in that the both say "evaluate `b` then become the thunk `a + b`".  Given the non precision in the consequences of `par` no other difference can be gleamed from the language definition.  Rather, on your particular compiler/runtime they might do slightly different things.